# BaseGameUtils import using Eclipse

Tags: android

Hey :) I am trying to add the BaseGameUtils library to my workspace, I am using this guide: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init , I have downloaded from here :https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/ The BaseGameUtils sample but when I am trying to import it using Eclipse it gives me so many wrong things like Main,MainActivity and not the real BaseGameUtils, what is wrong here?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nabin thx, posted there :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to run "make_eclipse_compat" script, located at Scripts/make_eclipse_compat in order to be able to import all of these projects using eclipse (they are created to use by Android-Studio by default).

Once you have run the script, a new folder called "eclipse_compat" will be created. You need to import the projects located at THAT folder. So, import BaseGameUtils, mark it as library and add a google_play_services as a library dependence.

Hope it helps

Comment: What if no folder is created at all? I run the script but nothing happens, even in administrator mode.
Should the new folder appear in the same directory of the script?