# how do you run a script

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, google-play-services

I read these instructions:
[BaseGameUtils import using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457651/basegameutils-import-using-eclipse)

It says you need to run "make_eclipse_compat" script.

Stupid question: How do I run the script on windows?
I tried the following:

```
start key

cmd.exe (run as administrator)

cd c:\android-basic-samples-master\scripts

run make_eclipse_compat
```

But that writes not output (no error message either) and does not create the eclipse_compat folder.
I cannot simply double click the script as it has no file ending.
From looking at the file in text editor I'd say it looks rather like a batch file. But appending .bat and running that does not work either.

What is the correct way to run the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the file and the first line says #!/bin/sh

According to the internet that means it is a bourne shell script which you run using bash.exe
So I installed cygwin, copied bash.exe to the android-basic-samples-master folder,
then in cmd.exe executed

```
bash Scripts/make_eclipse_compat
```

and the script finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `run`.  In Windows, if there is a `.bat` script, you simple execute:

```
make_eclipse_compat
```

or

```
make_eclipse_compat.bat
```

In the directory that has the script.

Comment: I tried that. It says "The command make_eclipse_compat is either misspelled or could not be found. As I said, the script has no file ending and there is no .bat file.